# Hide bootstrap navbar on mobile and show a button instead to show the collapsed navbar dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap navbar, and it collapses fine on small screens, shows the navbar-toggle and the dropdown menu if I click on the navbar-toggle. Standard behavior.

I want, however, to hide the entire navbar ribbon on small screens and just show a button on top middle part of the screen. When I click on this button, it should open the dropdown navbar. This is my html:

```
<div class="navbar-show">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" onclick="document.getElementById('toggle-button').click();">
        <img height="50px" width="50px" src="img/logo3.gif">
    </button> </div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-ng-controller="GlobalAuthCtrl">    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" id="toggle-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://gliderforecast.com"><img height="50px" width="48px" src="img/logo3.gif"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

My css:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    .navbar{
        display:none;
    }
    .navbar-show {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
.navbar-show {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

It shows the regular navbar on large screens, hides the navbar and shows the button on small screens, but I cannot get it show the collapsed navbar dropdown when I click on the button. Please guide me in the right direction. A completely different approach is also fine, just have the required functionality. JQuery is not preferred, (I am using angularJS) but can use it too.

Comment: can you share link in Jsfiddle?

are you using bootstrap Js and one jquery Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the #toggle-button part. And try:

```
<div class="navbar-show">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <img height="50px" width="50px" src="img/logo3.gif">
    </button> 
</div>
```

Bootstrap links it's JS part through data- attributes here.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, the data-toggle and data-target attributes of the button make bootstrap JS kick in and hide/show the navbar. Nice and easy :)